# Magento 2.4 on Nginx cannot find CSS and JS files

Tags: nginx, magento2

Been trying for 3 days now but I cannot get it to work. I succesfully installed Magento and everything but when I go to the website all CSS and JS files cannot be found.

When I look in the request it always have /versionxxxxx/ in the url so probably the rewrites are not setup properly.

I tried adding this code to my server block:

```
location /static/ {
    # Uncomment the following line in production mode
    # expires max;

    # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
    location ~ ^/static/version {
        rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static/$2 last;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|html|json)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
           rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}
```

but unfortunately all files still return a 404 not found.
An example file:

> /pub/static/version1600350960/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/requirejs/require.js

the file does exist on my FTP in the correct directory, but the "version" name is not in the directory.

Can anyone please help me out as I am clueless on how to fix this in NGINX.

Comment: Try removing the last `if` block.

Comment: That indeed solved the issue Richard, thanks a lot! only (new) problem I have now is that when I go to a new page i.e. https://www.example.com/customer/account/create/ I get a 404 NOT FOUND error thrown :(